# Bluetooth connections from Android to Arduino close immediately

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm new with [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29)... and [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) :/ I tried to modify the BluetoothChat example to make one project of my school, but I still receiving these messages from the LogCat:

```
04-14 16:14:06.399: I/BluetoothSocket(22238): connect() to  00:06:66:4D:61:F8 on port 0
04-14 16:14:06.399: D/BluetoothSppPort(22238): Creating a BluetoothSpp proxy object
04-14 16:14:06.414: D/BluetoothSocket(22238): closed: SppPort closed() for port 0
```

I'm trying to connect with a Bluetooth Mate - Clase 2 [silver] RN-42. How can I fix this problem?

I can send my code. Like I said I'm totally new with Android and Java...

Comment: Does the original BluetoothChat example work? Can you share your code?